# How can I pass data from redux-form via redux-saga into a component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-saga

I am trying to figure out how `redux-form` works with `redux-saga`.

### Expected Flow:

I have a `redux-form` inside a `selectbox`, which includes two options. Selecting an option will trigger an API call to request data. `handleOptionSaga` will handle this data and will show it inside container.

### **Actual Flow:**

The data isn't passed inside the container after I select an option.

Here is my code;

```
//ACTİONS
import FILTER_ITEMS from './FilterOptions.constants';
export const formFilterRequest = values => ({
    type: FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_REQUEST,
    values
});
export const formFilterSuccess = data => ({
    type: FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_SUCCESS,
    jsonData: data
});
export const formFilterFail = () => ({
    type: FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_FAILURE
});
```

```
// REDUCER
const JsonDataReducer = (state : Object = initialState, action : Object) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state
            };
        case FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                jsonData: action.data
            };
        case FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

```
//REDUX SAGA
function* handleOptionSaga({ values }) {
    yield put(startSubmit('optionFilterForm'));
    console.log('values ', values);
    yield delay(2000);

    if (values && values.selectedOption === '1') {
        const { data } = yield call(
            axios.get,
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/10'
        );
        if (data) {
            yield put(getOptionActions.formFilterSuccess(data));
        }
    } else if (values && values.selectedOption === '2') {
        const { data } = yield call(
            axios.get,
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/20'
        );
        if (data) {
            yield put(getOptionActions.formFilterSuccess(data));
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    yield put(setSubmitSucceeded('optionFilterForm'));
    yield put(stopSubmit('optionFilterForm'));
}

export default function* flightSearchFormSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_REQUEST, handleOptionSaga);
    yield takeEvery(FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_SUCCESS, handleOptionSaga);
}
```

Comment: You are passing data to your state with `put` - I don't see the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something weird in your `FORM_FILTER_SUCCESS` flow.

Here, you set `jsonData` to hold the data from the API call:

```
export const formFilterSuccess = (data) => ({
  type: FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_SUCCESS,
  jsonData:data
});
```

But here, you are trying to access `action.data` instead of `action.jsonData`:

```
case FILTER_ITEMS.FORM_FILTER_SUCCESS:
    return {
        ...state,
        jsonData: action.data <--- Try to use action.jsonData here
    };
```

Welcome to Stack Overflow!